# Currency exchange while using PayPal iOS sdk

Tags: ios, paypal, sdk, payment-gateway

I am developing online shopping App for iPhone. For financial transaction, I have used PayPal SDK and also created sandbox accounts for both buyer and receiver having US based account. I also had a test with US currency (USD) and credit/debit happens perfectly on both the accounts.

But, now I need to give support of non-USD currency, i.e INR as my App will be distributed over India. The only bottleneck is, INR is not in Paypal’s currency support list unfortunately. What should I do? Suppose, buyer buys product worth 100.00 INR and buyer have US based account having $ 500.00 balance. Now at end of transaction, based on exchange rate of these two currencies, amount should be deducted from buyer's account.

How can I manage this kind of multi-currency transaction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Pratik It sounds like your app will need to do its own currency conversion from INR to USD, and then perform the PayPal transaction in USD.

There are [many online currency converters](https://www.google.com/search?q=currency+converter&client=safari&rls=en&biw=1336&bih=1308&ei=qq4-VNXHHpHgoATr44CADQ&start=0&sa=N), including [some that return their results as JSON](https://www.google.com/search?q=currency+converter+json&client=safari&rls=en&biw=1336&bih=1308&ei=Na8-VLjNHI3uoASYtoHgCg&start=0&sa=N).

Comment: Thanks Dave Goldman for reply. As per you suggested, I should convert Non-USD currency to USD and then perform  PayPal transaction in USD. Now, suppose both do not have US based account i.e. INR and EUR. We can do conversion, but question is how can I know which country based account the receiver has ? If it was fixed that I need converion from Non-USD to USD, I could do it straight forward.

Comment: @Pratik things would definitely be better for you if PayPal accepted INR! Probably that will happen at some time in the future. In the meantime, I suppose that your app will need to ask the customer to choose from a list of currently-supported currencies, before performing the PayPal transaction, so that you can create the `PayPalPayment` object accordingly.

Comment: Dave Goldman, from your answer of my question you posted earlier on, I got one idea. I have the source currency INR (or whatever), I can convert it to USD and then debit/credit will occur only in USD, I don't have any problem if debit/credit occurs in USD. Actually, while asking question, my goal is to be sure that _conversion calculation_ take place properly. So as per your suggestion, I can use a API to convert INR (or whatever) to USD. I am one step forward now. But, I am confused which API to use. I mean, which is the reliable API ?

Comment: @Pratik I don't know the relative merits of the various currency converters.

Comment: Ok Dave Goldman. Now tell me if you know, what happens if I send payment (through iOS PayPal sdk) in USD and the receiver has UK based account having currency type GBP. Will PayPal automatically convert USD to GBP as per exchange rate and credit corresponding amount in GBP ? (PayPal supports both USD and GBP). If __YES__, then I always just need to do currency conversion from INR(or any currency regardless of PayPal supports or not) to USD, and then perform the PayPal transaction in USD. PayPal then do currency conversion at receiver end. And thus, my question will end up.

Comment: @Pratik the merchant account receiving the payment can be set to block currencies that they do not hold, or to accept them. But now you are getting beyond my expertise. So for further questions, I'd suggest that you contact PayPal's [developer support](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support).

Comment: Dave Goldman, the method I mentioned in my last comment works perfectly. I tried it on sandbox and it's working fine. PayPal does currency conversion automatically (for currencies it does support). So, I will go with it. Solution given by you worked for me. Thanks Dave Goldman for your continuous support. I will add comment in future in case of any query.